# invokeAndWait never called in Java 7

Tags: java, jvm, java-7

I would like to update my program to Java 7, but when I run it, it remains blocked. I create a UI with `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait`:

```
 SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createUI(MyManagerClass.getInstance());
        }
    });
```

However, `run` is never called. I don't understand why, because with Java 6 it work, and if I look at the thread I can't find deadlock.

All code:

```
public class MainGUI extends SingleFrameApplication {
    protected void startup() {
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        MyManagerClass.getInstance().setMainPanel(panel);
        show(panel);
        Worker.post(new Job() {
            @Override
            public Object run() {
                initUI();
                return null;
            }
        });
        getMainView().getFrame().pack();
        getMainView().getFrame().setResizable(false);

        panel.repaint();
    }
    private void initUI(){
        MyUIClass.init(MyManagerClass.getInstance());
    }
}

public class MyUIClass {
    public static void init(MyManagerClass class){
        JPanel panel = class.getMainPanel();
        panel.add(getComponent());
    }

    protected JComponent getComponent() {
        if (panel == null) {
            panel = new JPanel();
            fillPanel();
        }
        return panel;
    }

    protected void fillPanel() {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    createUI(MyManagerClass.getInstance());
                }
            });
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error(e, e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            log.error(e, e);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you set breakpoints to verify that it really isn't executed?

Comment: Make sure you are not calling this on the event dispatch thread.

Comment: Yes, I set breakpoint and it's never execute run method
And I check I wasn't on the event dispatch thread

Comment: Can you post a little bit more context around the invokeAndWait call? If applicable, try invokeLater(..).

Comment: And just out of curiosity, did you add the check for the EDT before the call to invokeAndWait?

Comment: I didn't add check, but when I display `EventQueue.isDispatchThread()` I have `false`. What I don't understand is that work with Java 6

Comment: Well, the basic premise of the invokeAndWait(..) method is that all other events currently queued on the EDT are processed first, then your runnable. Something else must be blocking the EDT. Post more context around the invokeAndWait call.

Comment: I just post most of the code

Comment: Does Worker.post(..) spawn up a new thread?

Comment: Yes because if I call initUI() out of this, I am on EDT.

Comment: Right. In that case you are manipulating UI components outside of the EDT, which should not be done. The entire point of invokeAndWait is to run code (that manipulates UI components) on the EDT. Solution: do not spawn a new thread but invoke initUI() directly within startup() (which is run on the EDT) and remove the then unecessary call to invokeAndWait?

Comment: Ok thanks, it's work whitout invokeAndWait. But why it worked with java 6 ?

Comment: Can't really say. Maybe Java 6's event queue works differently and your bug did not surface due to it. The main thing is that your code is now (probably) correct.